# Anchors disappearing under fixed navbar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having the classic problem of my anchors disappearing under my fixed navbar. I've tried various solutions on stackoverflow but none of them have worked. I'm using a flexbox. Since it's for a fcc assignment, I want to keep to vanilla html/css at the moment. No bootstrap or JS.

I also want to keep my flexbox in one piece of 4 adjoining squares.

Is this possible?

My [codepen](https://codepen.io/JammyPiece/pen/QxYgQb) is here.

```
<main>
<div class="flex-container">

  <div id="womens"class="anchor">Women's</div>
    <div id="mens" class="anchor">Men's</div>
  <div id="apparel" class="anchor">Apparel</div>
 <div id="accessories" class="anchor">Accessories</div>
</div>
<div id="reviews" class="anchor">
<h2>PRODUCT REVIEWS</h2><iframe width="560" height="315"  id="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/S1ny0G1FaDI" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
<div class="grid-item"><h2>SUBSCRIBE</h2>
  <p>If you would like to be kept upto date with our latest news, products and offers, enter your email address in the space below.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: With positioning...you can't. Unless you know the height and offset the next element by that much.

Comment: you also have a few html errors, example, put a space after id="womens" class="anchor"

Comment: corrected. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Seems fixed. Set my anchor position to relative and it's finally working.